# Group transition with dynamic list as a whole

Tags: vue.js

I have a `data_sets`. I need to take out a certain dataset (`data_source` in the snipped), filter it (`itemList` in the snippet) and display it, with any simple group transition, preferably `list` transition in Vue's [official guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#enter-leave-transitions)

---

[This](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) is a snippet that I created on https://sfc.vuejs.org/ to play around.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <transition-group name="list" mode="out-in">
      <li v-for="item in itemList" :key="item.id">
        {{item.content}}
        </li>
      </transition-group>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="changeDatasource(0)">
    Dataset 1
  </button>
  <button @click="changeDatasource(1)">
    Dataset 2
  </button>
  
  <button @click="changeDatasource(2)">
    Dataset 3
  </button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        data_sets: [
          [{
              id: 1,
              content: "Frog",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              content: "Elephant",
              active: 0,
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              content: "Racoon",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 8,
              content: "Cheetah",
              active: 1,
            },
          ],
          [{
              id: 4,
              content: "Rooster",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 5,
              content: "Cow",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 6,
              content: "Cat",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 7,
              content: "Dog",
              active: 0,
            },
          ],
          [{
              id: 10,
              content: "Lion",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 11,
              content: "Shark",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 12,
              content: "Bee",
              active: 0,
            },
            {
              id: 13,
              content: "Cockroaches",
              active: 0,
            },
          ],
        ],
        data_source: [],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      itemList: {
        get() {
          return this.data_source.filter((item) => item.active)
        },

        set(newValue) {
          //this.itemList = newValue; <--
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeDatasource: function(id) {
        //this.itemList = [] <--
        this.data_source = this.data_sets[id];
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .list-enter-active,
  .list-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  .list-enter-from,
  .list-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
</style>
```

---

When clicking on buttons to choose a data set, you can see the transition is not okay: old items still present when the new ones come in. The expected order should be: old items disappears, then new items come in.

---

It's very likely because `itemList` is replaced as a whole at a time. So I've tried to:

1. Empty `itemList` = [],
2. Continue to make the changes. (the commented part in the snippet)

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Guess it bounds to some kind of infinite loop, at this point I'm completely pointless.

I've also messed around with [transition mode](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#transition-modes), it isn't better.

My question is there any way to apply transition to list as a whole like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by working around with `setTimeout` and `setInterval` and changed from `computed` propery to `watch`.
Content shifting is there but a little CSS and JavaScript manipulation will fix it. Not the best solution but by now that's what I can think of.

[Result snippet](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <transition-group name="list">
      <li v-for="item in itemList" :key="item.id">
        {{item.content}}
        </li>
      </transition-group>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="changeDatasource(0)">
    Dataset 1
  </button>
  <button @click="changeDatasource(1)">
    Dataset 2
  </button>
  
  <button @click="changeDatasource(2)">
    Dataset 3
  </button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        data_sets: [
          [{
              id: 1,
              content: "Frog",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              content: "Elephant",
              active: 0,
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              content: "Racoon",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 8,
              content: "Cheetah",
              active: 1,
            },
          ],
          [{
              id: 4,
              content: "Rooster",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 5,
              content: "Cow",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 6,
              content: "Cat",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 7,
              content: "Dog",
              active: 0,
            },
          ],
          [{
              id: 10,
              content: "Lion",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 11,
              content: "Shark",
              active: 1,
            },
            {
              id: 12,
              content: "Bee",
              active: 0,
            },
            {
              id: 13,
              content: "Cockroaches",
              active: 0,
            },
          ],
        ],
        data_source: [],
        itemList: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeDatasource: function(id) {
        //this.itemList = [] <--
        this.data_source = this.data_sets[id];
      }
    },
    watch: {
      data_source: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        let initialLength = this.itemList.length;
        if (initialLength > 0) {
          this.itemList = [];
        }
        let dataLength = newValue.length;
        let interval = 200;
        let i = 0;
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (typeof newValue[i - 1] != 'undefined') {
              this.itemList.push(newValue[i - 1])
            }
          }, interval)
          if (i === dataLength - 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
          }
          i++;

        }, interval)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .list-enter-active,
  .list-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  .list-enter-from,
  .list-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
</style>
```

---